# How to link two dropdown lists using data-attribute instead of their values?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

How can I edit the following code so as to make it work using data-attributes? The reason for this is because in my example values will not be the same for the two dropdown lists so I want to link them with something else, like data-attribute.

```
<select name="" id="" class="select">
    <option value="">Select</option>
    <option value="1">Value 1</option>
    <option value="2">Value 2</option>
</select>
<select name="" id="" class="select">
    <option value="">Select</option>
    <option value="1">Value 1</option>
    <option value="2">Value 2</option>
</select>


$(function () {
    var select = $('select.select');
    select.change(function () {
        select.not(this).val(this.value);
    });
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should work (**synchronizing lists by data attributes**):

```
<select name="" id="" class="select">
    <option data-id='1' value="">Select</option>
    <option data-id='2' value="1">Value 1</option>
    <option data-id='3' value="2">Value 2</option>
</select>
<select name="" id="" class="select">
    <option data-id='1' value="5">Select</option>
    <option data-id='2' value="3">Value 1</option>
    <option data-id='3' value="4">Value 2</option>
</select>


(function () {
    var select = $('select.select'), opt, dataAttr;
    select.change(function () {
        dataAttr = $(this).find(':selected').data('id');
        select.not($(this)).each(function(){
           if (opt = $(this).find('[data-id='+ dataAttr +']')){
               $(opt).prop('selected', true);
           }
        });
    });
})();
```